# Control.Location vs. Control.Top and Control.Left

Tags: .net, winforms, controls

I stumbled upon the fact that you can set the position of a Control inside a Form by both [`Location`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.location%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and a combination of [`Top`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.top%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Left`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.left%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
`Top` and `Left` are according to MSDN (see links) equivalent to `Location.Y` and `Location.X`.

The only difference I found is that `Location` can also be used for Forms, but is there any difference between setting the position of a Control by changing the `Location` or by changing `Top` and `Left`?

Comment: They are convenience properties.  Try `this.Location.X += 1;` to see why using Left is convenient.

Comment: @HansPassant it is even more inconvenient: `this.Location.X = new Point(this.Location.X+1, this.Location.Y`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no practical difference

This is [the source code for the Top property](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,f8509a5674204172)

```
public int Top
{
    get { return y; }
    set { SetBounds(x, value, width, height, BoundsSpecified.Y); }
}
```

and this is [the source code for the Location property](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,fe6221f0995f8f41)

```
public Point Location
{
    get { return new Point(x, y); }
    set { SetBounds(value.x, value.y, width, height, BoundsSpecified.Location); }
}
```

As you can see the only important difference is the fact that Point is a structure and the get accessor create a new structure when returning the value. This means that code like this is not legal

```
// CS1612 Cannot modify the return value of 'Form.Location' because it is not a variable
yourForm.Location.X = 500;
```

So, what is better? It is a matter of preference or if you need to change only the Top or Left property or if you need to set both. Need to add also that using the Location property causes the setting of both X and Y internal properties because the BoundsSpecified.Location flag enum is defined as

```
 ....
 Location = X | Y,
 ....
```